# Curve fit or interpolation in a semilogy plot using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, curve-fitting, extrapolation

I have very few data points and I want to create a line to best fit the data points when plotted in a semilogy scale. I have tried curve-fit and cubic interpolation from scipy, but none of them seems to be very reasonable to me compared to the data trend.

I would kindly ask you to check if there is a more efficient way to create a straight line fit for the data. Probably extrapolation can do, but I did not find a good documentation on extrapolation on python.

your help is very appreciated

```
import sys
import os
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimization
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy import interpolate
```

[image]

```
Mass500 = numpy.array([ 13.938 , 13.816,  13.661,  13.683,  13.621,  13.547,  13.477,  13.492,  13.237,
  13.232,  13.07,   13.048,  12.945,  12.861,  12.827,  12.577,  12.518])

y500 = numpy.array([  7.65103978e-06,   4.79865790e-06,   2.08218909e-05,   4.98385924e-06,
   5.63462673e-06,   2.90785458e-06,   2.21166794e-05,   1.34501705e-06,
   6.26021870e-07,   6.62368879e-07,   6.46735547e-07,   3.68589447e-07,
   3.86209019e-07,   5.61293275e-07,   2.41428755e-07,   9.62491134e-08,
   2.36892162e-07])



plt.semilogy(Mass500, y500, 'o')


# interpolation
f2 = interp1d(Mass500, y500, kind='cubic')
plt.semilogy(Mass500, f2(Mass500), '--')


# curve-fit
def line(x, a, b):
    return 10**(a*x+b)

#Initial guess.
x0     = numpy.array([1.e-6, 1.e-6])

print optimization.curve_fit(line, Mass500, y500, x0)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, Mass500, y500)
print popt
plt.semilogy(Mass500, line(Mass500, popt[0], popt[1]), 'r-')



plt.legend(['data', 'cubic', 'curve-fit'], loc='best')

show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many regression functions available in numpy and scipy.
  [`scipy.stats.lingress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) is one of the simpler functions, and it returns common linear regression parameters.

Here are two options for fitting semi-log data:

1. Plot Transformed Data
2. Rescale Axes and Transform Input/Output Function Values

**Given**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


# Data
mass500 = np.array([ 
    13.938 , 13.816,  13.661,  13.683,
    13.621,  13.547,  13.477,  13.492,
    13.237,  13.232,  13.07,   13.048,  
    12.945,  12.861,  12.827,  12.577,  
    12.518
])

y500 = np.array([  
    7.65103978e-06,   4.79865790e-06,   2.08218909e-05,   4.98385924e-06,
    5.63462673e-06,   2.90785458e-06,   2.21166794e-05,   1.34501705e-06,
    6.26021870e-07,   6.62368879e-07,   6.46735547e-07,   3.68589447e-07,
    3.86209019e-07,   5.61293275e-07,   2.41428755e-07,   9.62491134e-08,
    2.36892162e-07
])
```

**Code**

*Option 1*: Plot Transformed Data

```
# Regression Function
def regress(x, y):
    """Return a tuple of predicted y values and parameters for linear regression."""
    p = sp.stats.linregress(x, y)
    b1, b0, r, p_val, stderr = p
    y_pred = sp.polyval([b1, b0], x)
    return y_pred, p

# Plotting
x, y = mass500, np.log(y500)                      # transformed data
y_pred, _ = regress(x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, "mo", label="Data")
plt.plot(x, y_pred, "k--", label="Pred.")
plt.xlabel("Mass500")
plt.ylabel("log y500")                            # label axis
plt.legend()
```

Output

[image]

A simple approach is to plot transformed data and label the appropriate log axes.

---

*Option 2*: Rescale Axes and Transform Input/Output Function Values

**Code**

```
x, y = mass500, y500                              # data, non-transformed
y_pred, _ = regress(x, np.log(y))                 # transformed input             

plt.plot(x, y, "o", label="Data")
plt.plot(x, np.exp(y_pred), "k--", label="Pred.") # transformed output
plt.xlabel("Mass500")
plt.ylabel("y500")
plt.semilogy()
plt.legend()
```

Output

[image]

A second option is to alter the axes to semi-log scales (via `plt.semilogy()`).  Here the non-transformed data naturally appears linear.  Also notice the labels represent the data as-is.

To make an accurate regression, all that remains is to *transform data passed into the regression function* (via [`np.log(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) or [`np.log10(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html)) in order to *return the proper regression parameters*.  This transformation  is immediately reversed when plotting predicated values using a complementary operation, i.e. [`np.exp(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) or `10**x`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a line that will look good on log-y scale, then fit a line to the logarithms of the y-values.

```
def line(x, a, b):
    return a*x+b
popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, Mass500, np.log10(y500))
plt.semilogy(Mass500, 10**line(Mass500, popt[0], popt[1]), 'r-')
```

This is it; I only left out the cubic interpolation part which didn't seem relevant.

[image: fit]